# Python Pandas Update Values According to Multiples of "x" Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My input dataframe:

```
    Order   Package
1    5         6
2    4         3
3    7         10
4    2         1
5    9         4 
6    12        5      
7    1         1
```

> If my "Order" values are lower than "Package" values it should be
>   updated as "0(zero)".
>
> If my "Order" values are greater than "Package"
>   values it should be updated as maximum multiple of its "Package"
>   values. For example, for the 5th row "Order" values "9" should be updated as "8" due to "Package" value 4 for this row.
>
> If "Order" values are equal to "Package", "Order" values should remain the same like the last row.

Desired Output is;

```
     Order
1      0
2      3
3      0
4      2
5      8
6      10
7      1
```

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: As written, you're basically asking us to do it for you. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Shouldn't row 6 be `10`, not `2`?

Comment: `maximum multiple of its "Package" values`, where does the 8 come from? there are no eights..

Comment: yes you are right @user3483203. i edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
df['Order'] -= df['Order'] % df['Packages']
```

Output:

```
   Order  Package
1      0        6
2      3        3
3      0       10
4      2        1
5      8        4
6     10        5
7      1        1
```

Comment: Does your data have `NaN` values or `0` in `package` column?

Comment: Nope, Order column

Comment: Then `fillna(0)` on `Order`?